# How to rearrange Grid columns?

Tags: magento2

I've tried with drag/drop, but it doesn't save. It should be ID - Thumbnail - SKU - Manufacturer - Type - Quantity - Color - Size - Price - Status.

[image]

How can I change the order? Is it in Grid.php or maybe product_listing.xml?

Thanks

Comment: try to drag and drop.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't save. When I refresh it resets.

Comment: it was worked for me.

Comment: Drag and drop worked for me. I have checked

Comment: The reason why it's not saving is because it's not sending the AJAX request, the /bookmark/save/key. It sends this request when toggling which columns to display, but not when dragging the grid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem, since Magento 2.1 you can't rearrange columns in "Single Store Mode", the bug has been known since Nov 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change **`sortOrder`** in below file :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml
```

or

`app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to overwrite below file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml
```

You can change order using `<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">44</item>`.

You need to clear entry "product_listing" from table `ui_bookmark` in your database. That entry is caching sort order of the grid columns in db.

After making above changed clear cache from admin or command.